# Inject uploadify filename/filepath programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, uploadify

My typical usage of **uploadify** [www.uploadify.com] follows the following pattern:

```
// to initialize
$("#divid").uploadify({
    "uploader": ...,
    "script": ...,
    "auto": ...,
    "folder": ...,
    "multi": ...,
    "onSelect": function(evt, id, fileobj) {

    }),
    "onComplete": function(a, b, c) {

    })
});

// If I need to change some setting
$("#divid").uploadifySettings({
    "script", ...
});

// finally fire up file upload
$("#divid").uploadifyUpload();
```

Now, by doing so, am presented with [Browse] functionality/feature wherein I can browse for the file that I will proceed to upload. Now, I would like to know if there is a way to programmatically inject the filename/filepath [say you have the actual path and filename and you dont want the user to have to browse for it].

I have looked at the API but can quite figure out if it should be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot control the path.  Uploadify is built on top of flash.  So what you are seeing is the Flash file dialogue.  The [flash documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html) states:

```
The FileReference and FileReferenceList classes do not let you 
set the default file location for the dialog box that the browse() or 
download() methods generate
```

Answer (score 1):

No, AFAIK this is not possible.